# Git: Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, intellij-idea, proxy, atlassian-sourcetree, http-status-code-503

I checked a lot of post related to this issue, but nothing seems to fix my problem. So now I hope you guys can give me the magic answer.

I'm using Intellij (but also tried it with SourceTree) to pull/push/clone a repository from Fisheye. However I'm receiving the error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin

fatal: unable to access 'https://myUser@myUrl/fisheye/git/myRepo.git/': Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Hints about 503 means a temporary downtime due to maintenance don't work for me, since this issue last for a week now.

Hints about wrong/missing proxy settings don't seem to work either. I setup http and https proxy for system git and for the IDE (Intellij).

It worked before, I was able to clone the repository. Then I created a new branch, made some changes and wanted to push it back to the master.

I really looking forward for some clever tips.

Thanks so far

**UPDATE**

I added:

`export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1`
`export GIT_TRACE=1`
`export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`

and I received the following **log**:

```
$ git fetch
trace: built-in: git 'fetch'
trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://Username@myWebService.de/randomGit.git/'
* Couldn't find host myWebService in the _netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 15.46.16.11...
* Connected to myProxy.com (15.46.16.11) port 8080 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to myWebService.de:443
> CONNECT myWebService.de:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: webapp-entw.mlp.de:443
User-Agent: git/1.9.5.msysgit.1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 732
<
* Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://Username@myWebService.de/randomGit.git/': Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: `origin  https://[myUser]@[myGit].git (fetch)`        `origin  https://[myUser]@[myGit].git (push)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my proxy doesn't recognizes the webapp address, so I installed Privoxy and told him to pass every request except those, which are intended for my git. And it works.

So if I have to connect to the repository I skip the proxy and connect directly.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same error code.  For me, the symptom was that I could successfully push to a remote repo, but not pull...  In my case, it appeared to turn out to be a name resolution issue.

First, I found these settings to shed more light on the network events.

```
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

With these settings, I received a trace like this:

```
PROMPT$ git pull
...
15:21:17.015575 run-command.c:351       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://gitub.com/USERNAME/REPO'
* Couldn't find host gitub.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying PROXY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS...
* Connected to (PROXY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS) port 80 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to gitub.com:443
> CONNECT gitub.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: gitub.com:443
User-Agent: git/2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 787
< 
* Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
* Connection #0 to host PROXY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS left intact
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitub.com/USERNAME/REPO/': Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I did some pinging to github.com, then www.github.com, and noticed some different results.  This prompted me to update my origin URL as follows.

```
git remote set-url origin https://www.github.com/USERNAME/REPO
```

Simply adding "www." into the origin URL resolved my connection issue in this case.  No more 503s -- push and pulls both succeed.

UPDATE

Based on your updated trace, this looks very similar to the issue that I had.  What you might try is to temporarily substitute the actual IP address of the repository server that you are using (rather than hostname).  If that works, then look into solutions for name resolution, like perhaps modifying /etc/hosts.  Also, can you confirm that you tried git remote set-url origin to include the full hostname and not just the domain name?

Comment: so I should change `origin https://[myUser]@[myGit].git` to `origin https://www.[myUser]@[myGit].git (push)`?

Comment: so I added
`export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1`